# Fresh build for objective C IOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

If I want the new build to be clean of all of the previous settings from the past build? Is there something like make clean?

Comment: you mean project build right?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Xcode? Yes, the Product->Clean menu option does a clean.

Comment: I only see Build -> Clean, but it's not clickable